# Firebase File Upload Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom-events, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a file to Firebase storage using JavaScript.

```
var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                  var file = e.target.files[0];
                  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(userID + '/profilePicture/'+file.name);
                  storageRef.put(file);
              });
```

The code above works fine but now I am trying to upload image on form submit
which is not working:

```
<form>
<input type="file" id="fileButton"/>
<input type="submit" value="push" onsubmit="myFunction()"/>
</form>
//function
function myFunction() {
            var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
          fileButton.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
              var file = e.target.files[0];
              var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(userID + '/profilePicture/'+file.name);
              storageRef.put(file);
          });  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `myFunction()` is simply adding the Listener to that button, and not really uploading the file to the database. What you should do is:

```
function myFunction() {
    var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
    var file = fileButton.files[0];
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(userID + '/profilePicture/'+file.name);
    storageRef.put(file);
}
```